# How get collection view to controls search results in tableview?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, search, uicollectionview

ive been trying to index my search results through the collection view above my tableview so that when I press a cell in the collection view it can index the results in the table as seen in the image below

So far the code works to an extent where that once I press a cell in the collection view it will place the text of the selected category in the search bar and will get the search results, but then moments later the simulator crashes on me with the error ***Thread 1: Fatal error: Index out of range*** on `cell.configure(withProduct: itemInventory[indexPath.row])` in the cellForRowAt in the tableview

Thanks in advance for helping

[image: My View]

```
import UIKit
import Firebase
import FirebaseFirestore

class HomeController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var searchBar: UISearchBar!
    @IBOutlet weak var collectionView: UICollectionView!
    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

    var categorys: [Category] = []
    var searchActive : Bool = false

    var itemInventory: [ItemList] = []
    var itemSetup: [ItemList] = []

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        categorys = Category.createCategoryArray()

        searchBar.delegate = self

    }
    // fetches Firebase Data
    func fetchProducts(_ completion: @escaping ([ItemList]) -> Void) {
        let ref = Firestore.firestore().collection("products")
        ref.addSnapshotListener { (snapshot, error) in
            guard error == nil, let snapshot = snapshot, !snapshot.isEmpty else {
                return
            }
            completion(snapshot.documents.compactMap( {ItemList(dictionary: $0.data())} ))
        }
    }
}

extension HomeController: UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {
    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

        if searchBar.text != "" {
            return self.itemInventory.count
        }
        return itemSetup.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        guard let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "ItemCell") as ItemCell else { return UITableViewCell() }

        //search not empty
        if searchBar.text != "" {
            cell.configure(withProduct: itemInventory[indexPath.row])
        }else{
            cell.configure(withProduct: itemSetup[indexPath.row])
        }

        return cell
    }

}

extension HomeController: UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource{

    func numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return categorys.count
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "CategoryCell", for: indexPath) as! CategoryCell
        let category = categorys[indexPath.row]
        cell.setCategory(category: category)

        return cell
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "CategoryCell", for: indexPath) as! CategoryCell
        let category = categorys[indexPath.row]
        cell.setCategory(category: category)
        print("\(category): \(cell.categoryLbl.text!)")

        searchBar.text = cell.categoryLbl.text! //added this so I could get the search results from pressing a cell in the collection view
    }
}


extension HomeController : UISearchBarDelegate, UISearchDisplayDelegate {

    func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) {
        productInventory = self.itemSetup.filter({ (products) -> Bool in
            return products.name.range(of: searchText, options: [ .caseInsensitive, .diacriticInsensitive ]) != nil ||
                products.category.range(of: searchText, options: [ .caseInsensitive, .diacriticInsensitive ]) != nil 
        })

        self.tableView.reloadData()

    }

    func searchBarTextDidBeginEditing(_ searchBar: UISearchBar) {
        searchActive = true;
    }

    func searchBarTextDidEndEditing(_ searchBar: UISearchBar) {
        searchActive = false;
        self.searchBar.endEditing(true)
    }

    func searchBarCancelButtonClicked(_ searchBar: UISearchBar) {
        searchActive = false;
        self.searchBar.endEditing(true)
    }

    func searchBarSearchButtonClicked(_ searchBar: UISearchBar) {
        searchActive = false;
        self.searchBar.endEditing(true)
    }
}
```

---

```
class CategoryCell: UICollectionViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var categoryLbl: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var categoryView: UIView!

    func setCategory(category: Category) {
        categorylbl.text = category.categoryLabel
    }
}


import UIKit
import SDWebImage
import Firebase

class ItemCell: UITableViewCell {

    weak var product: ProductList!
    weak var infoDelegate: InfoDelegate?
    var addActionHandler: ((Int) -> Void)?

    @IBOutlet weak var productImage: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var productName: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var categoryLabel: UILabel!

    func configure(withProduct product: ProductList) {
        productName.text = product.name
        categoryLabel.text = product.category
        productImage.sd_setImage(with: URL(string: product.imageUrl))
    }

    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()

    }
}
```

---

```
class Category {
    var categoryLabel: String

    init(categoryLabel: String) {

        self.categoryLabel = categoryLabel

    }
    class func createCategoryArray() -> [Category] {

        var categorys: [Category] = []

        let category1 = Category(categoryLabel: "All")
        let category2 = Category(categoryLabel: "Veggies")
        let category3 = Category(categoryLabel: "Fruit")
        let category4 = Category(categoryLabel: "Bread")
        let category5 = Category(categoryLabel: "Drinks")
        let category6 = Category(categoryLabel: "Dairy")

        categorys.append(category1)
        categorys.append(category2)
        categorys.append(category3)
        categorys.append(category4)
        categorys.append(category5)
        categorys.append(category6)

        return categorys

    }
}

enum Cats: String {
    case all = ""          //to get all results in search
    case fruit = "Fruit"
    case veggies = "Veggies"
    case bread = "Bread"
    case drinks = "Drinks"
    case dairy = "Dairy"
}

import Foundation
import UIKit
import Firebase
import FirebaseFirestore

class ItemList {
    var id: String
    var name: String
    var category: String
    var imageUrl: String

    Init(id: String,
         name: String,
         category: String,
         imageUrl: String) {

        self.id = id
        self.name = name
        self.category = category
        self.imageUrl = imageUrl
    }

    convenience init(dictionary: [String : Any]) {
        let id = dictionary["id"] as? String ?? ""
        let name = dictionary["name"] as? String ?? ""
        let category =  dictionary["category"] as? String ?? ""
        let imageUrl =  dictionary["imageUrl"] as? String ?? ""


        self.init(id: id,
                  name: name,
                  category: category,
                  imageUrl: imageUrl)
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

This might be because you set filtered array to `productInventory` which isn’t used in Cell for row.